# Build iOS apps, Windows 7/10 & Jailbroken device

Tags: c++, ios, windows, build, jailbreak

I have an jailbroken iOS device and Windows 7/10. I would like to be able to easily build and compile (C++/Cocos2Dx) iOS games and directly test them on my device. I would also like to be able to share my code to OS X users so that they can also compile it using XCode (probably not a problem).

**What is the best way to do so?**

What I know (but may be partly wrong) :

- I could use virtual machines to simulate OS X but it seems to be slow and therefore not the best long-term solution.
- There are tools to compile iOS code with jailbroken iOS devices using some toolchain available on Cydia but I'm not really sure if and how it would work using the latest versions of iOS and using external libraries like Cocos2Dx. Plus it does not seem to be ultra convenient to compile then install and test your app on the device.
- I could use Marmalade but I'm not sure about including Cocos2Dx in it, it's not entirely free and I don't know if the code can easily be compiled in someone's else XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can rent a macOS machine though a service such as http://www.macincloud.com.
You could also buy a Mac Mini.